# Show level set is finite

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ be $C^1$ such that $\text{rank}(Df_p)=n$ for each $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $S\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be bounded. Prove that for every $y\in\mathbb{R}^m$ the set $\{x\in S:f(x)=y\}$ is finite.

My thought was to pick any $p\in\mathbb{R}^n$. Since $Df_p$ has full rank, it is invertible and so $\exists \ U\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ open such that $p\in U$ and $f|_{U}$ is a $C^1$ diffeomorphism onto its image. This implies (by invariance of dimension for homeomorphism) that $m=n$. Also, since every point $p$ is a regular point of $f$, we have that $f^{-1}(y)$ is a submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ of dimension $n-(m=n)=0$. Hence, $f^{-1}(y)$ is finite, so $S\cap f^{-1}(y)$ is finite.

I'm thinking my argument is not correct because I didn't use the fact that $S$ is bounded. If it is correct, does anyone know an argument that doesn't resort to invariance of dimension and the regular submanifold theorem?

Comment: If that set is infinite, there is a sequence of distinct points in it converging to some  x. That violates injectivity in a neighborhood of x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n<m$, consider $g:R^m\rightarrow R^m$ defined $g(x_1,..,x_m)=(f(x_1,..,x_n),x_{n+1},..,x_m)$ show that the rank of $g$ is $m$, thus $g$ is a local diffeomorphism since its rank is maximal. This implies that $g^{-1}(y)$ is discrete. This implies that $f^{-1}(y)=g^{-1}(y)\cap R^n\times\{0\}$ is also discrete. We deduce that $f^{-1}(y)\cap S$ is discrete, a discrete subset of a compact set is finite.